# get name of app which created the notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm working on an android application that listens for notifications. Is there any way to get the name of the app which created the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the package name first on receiving the new notification from the notification service::

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker = new String();
    if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
        ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    }
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;

    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
    Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
}
```

And then use the "pack" value to get the app name:

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
ApplicationInfo ai; 
try { 
     ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( pack, 0); 
} catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) { 
     ai = null; 
} 
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? 
pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

Comment: do you know how to get the small image with color? when I use statusBarNotification.getNotification().getSmallIcon() and convert it to jpeg, I'm getting grey image